# How to design a theme for a navigation based iphone app

Tags: iphone, user-interface, themes, user-experience

I am working on my first iphone app. Great so far with regards to functionality but the app itself looks dull and borderline retro. Any tips on how to design a user friendly and pleasant theme? I have a main menu (grouped uitableview).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many details that only the trained eye can see. I can only spot some of them.

For example, the world of beautiful apps is full of gradients, shadows, highlights, small contrasts and subtle (background) patterns.

How to learn this? Read design blogs, books, articles, etc. They like to discuss the pixels of the most beautiful apps and websites.

I also have learned a good amount of little details with tutorials on the web. For example, many css3 tutorials explain how to achieve many beautiful effects in a higher level. On the other hand, css2 would make you spend more time in "hacks" to achieve transparency, rounded corners, etc. That's why I think that css3 resources are a good way to learn how to do these beautiful widgets. (I only use them to notice some details that masters do)

This will take you some time... Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop, Omnigraph, or some other tool to mock up your view. There are kits out there with iPhone graphics, I believe omnigraph comes with iPhone stencils (i have never used it).

Interface builder is great and all but you cant do everything with it. What I often do is design the interface in IB and use that as a reference to create the views programatically. For example, say I want a custom table row ill add a view to IB, then click on size inspector.

[image: label][image]
[image][image]

```
- (void)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path 
{

//
// assume i already dequeued UITableViewCell *cell
// no need to specify float values, more readable
//
UILabel *label = 
    [[[UILabel alloc] 
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 109, 50)] 
        autorelease];
UITextField *textField = 
    [[[UITextField alloc] 
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(117, 0, 203, 50)] 
        autorelease];

//  
// Customize attributes based on interface builder values  
//  
NSArray * const labelVals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User Name", @"Password", nil];

label.text = [[labelVals objectAtIndex:[path row]] stringValue];
label.textColor = [UIColor plumColor];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

textField.placeholder = @"enter text here";
textField.borderStyle = whatever BorderStyleNone is;
// etc ...

[cell addSubview:label];
[cell addSubview:textField];

}
```

Comment: I do understand how to create objects and how to use IB however what I am asking is how to come up with a nice and pleasant theme for my app. Thanks

Comment: Dont use a lot of background colors, you dont want to distract the user from the information. Make sure its clear they can type into the table cells. subscribe to the UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit in your UITextFields and find the next text field to becomeFirstResponder, that way they dont have to tap on all the rows they can just press return. The point of my answer wasn't to show you the basics you probably already know, it was to show you how I do it sometimes - Mocking a theme up in IB first, then doing the work.